# Python deploy function using Fabric

Tags: python, python-2.x

Simple task - deploy war-file from TeamCity agent to remote web-server.

I realized it with `Fabric`, because of it make readable output, and give opportunity to login via SSH with RSA-key. Also - during deploy - build agent must make some additional steps - create backup, stop-start Tomcat service etc.

URL to deploy to can be passed via variable on build-server.

```
import os
import sys
import time

from fabric.api import run, env, put

VAR_PREFIX = 'bamboo_'

"""Cloudlibrary functions"""


def deploy(logger, rds_basedir):

    """Deploy cloudlibrary.war to remote box, passed via BASE_URL"""

    logger.logger.info('Running cloudlibrary.war deploy')

    # file to deploy
    local_file = 'target/cloudlibrary.war'
    # local_file = 'd:\\RDS\\rdsmanager\\file.txt'

    # file will be created during backup command
    back_file = '/home/ec2-user/backups/cloudlibrary/cloudlibrary_%s.war' % time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    # commands list
    status = 'sudo service tomcat7 status'
    backup = 'cp /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/cloudlibrary.war %s' % back_file
    check_bkp = 'file %s' % back_file
    tomcat_kill = 'sudo kill -9 $(cat /var/run/tomcat7.pid)'
    tomcat_start = 'sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat7 start'

    try:
        base_url = os.environ[VAR_PREFIX + 'BASE_URL']
        logger.logger.info('\nURL found %s' % base_url)
    except KeyError:
        base_url = 'www.dev.domain.com'
        logger.logger.info('URL variable not found, will default - %s' % base_url)

    # Fabric connection settings
    env.host_string  = base_url
    env.key_filename = [os.path.join(rds_basedir, '.ssh', 'rdsmanager_priv.openssh')]
    env.user = 'user'
    env.project_root = '/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps'

    logger.logger.info('Using URL: %s, user: %s, RDS-key: %s, Tomcat webapps: %s' % (env.host_string, env.user, env.key_filename[0], env.project_root))


    if os.path.isfile(local_file):
        # make backup of current cloudlibrary.war to ~/backup/cloulibrary
        run(backup)

        # if new file doesn't found - Fabric will exit
        run(check_bkp)

        # stop Omcat before put new war-file
        run(tomcat_kill)

        # put new builded war-file
        put(local_file, env.project_root)

        # start Tomcat
        run(tomcat_start)

        # cgeck it's status
        run(status)
    else:
        logger.logger.error('ERROR: file %s not found. Exit.' % local_file)
        sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Are you aware of the existence of [ftplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html)?

Comment: @Mast um... no... but - there is also tasks to start/stop Tomcat, not only copy war-file... plus - authorization possible with RSA key only;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Using `%` for string formatting is deprecated. You should be using `str.format()` instead. Here's how one would use `str.format()`: `print "Hello {0}.".format("world")`. `str.format()` also supports using keyword arguments. Here's an example of that: `print "Hello {word}.".format(word="world")`.
2. Near the end of the function `deploy`, underneath the `if` block with the condition `os.path.isfile(local_file)`, you have comments above every line. These are unnecessary and can be removed.
3. Finally, I'm not sure why you have square brackets, `[]`, around the value of the variable `env.key_filename`. If these aren't needed, they can be removed.